# Google Play Store App Reviewed On WearOS Devices

Tags: android, google-play, release, wear-os

Every time that I put out a release specified for Phone, tablets and chrome os I get an email from Google telling me that it has crashed on a WearOS and it does not meet the wear guidelines. I do have a companion WearOS App. However this occurs when I am releasing for Phones, Tablets, and Chrome OS. Specifically I am getting a SPLIT_BUNDLE 10 ERRROR. It seems that google is reviewing my app meant for phones on a wearOS device and therefore it is crashing because it is not meant for wearOS devices.

I have reached out and appealed to google multiple times. Usually it takes a few times of reaching out to google and getting rejected again for the release to finally be approved.